# C Language: command line input conversion to integer with ASCII math Error: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a command-line argument to an integer with ASCII math.
We already know the input argument is an integer from 2 to 10.
Here is my code:

```
int key = argv[2] - 48;
printf("%d", key);
```

And this is the Error message I got.

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 int key = argv[2] - 48;
           ^~~~
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `argv` is an array of pointers.

Comment: I suggest perhaps `int key = argv[2][0] - '0';` or even `int key = argv[1][0] - '0';` not knowing the details. Better still, use `strtol()`.

Answer (score 1):

`argv` has type `char **`, i.e. a pointer to `char *` strings, followed by a `NULL` pointer (C Standard, §5.1.2.2.1: 2).

`argv[2]` is a `char *` pointer, not an individual `char`. Your operation `argv[2] - 48` is not performing arithmetic on the numerical value of any character but rather performing arithmetic on a pointer.

If you want to perform arithmetic on the `char` values comprising the string *pointed to* by `argv[2]`, you could access its individual characters like this:

```
size_t len = strlen(argv[2]);
size_t i;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    permute(argv[2][i]); // made up function name
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; argv[2][i]; i++)` is sufficient, no need for `strlen()`. The arguments are nul-terminated strings. Good job with the standard cite.

Answer (score 0):

argv in command line argument represents array of pointers to chars. i.e. argv[1] represents array of characters. e.g. you passed 122 as argument then argv[1] is ['1', '2', '2'].
so you have to use atoi function if you want convert character array to integer. `int key = atoi(argv[1]);`

Comment: I can't use atoi() function. It's an assignment, and we have to solve it using only ASCII math.